# How to add remainder to an existing integer?

Tags: python

We were tasked to write a program that finds the total amount of plastic bottles that can be made from an initial number of plastic bottles (basically recycling plastic). We have x as the initial number of plastic bottles, and y as the number of plastic bottles needed to create a new plastic bottle.

For example, we need 2 bottles to create a new one. From 13 initial plastic bottles, we can create 25 new ones (including the 13 initial bottles we have). Here is how the logic goes:

```
13 // 2 = 6 rem. 1
7 // 2 = 3 rem. 1
4//2 = 2
2//2 = 1
13 (initial) + 6 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 25 bottles
```

I already understood what we're supposed to do and have created a program. However, I have I think a simple problem that got me stumped for several hours already. **I can't add the remainder to the quotient so that it will be included when I floor divide again**. Here is my current progress:

```
x = 13  #just an example
y = 2  #just an example
bottles = [x]
sample = x
while sample // y != 0:
    sample = sample // y
    bottles.append(sample)
print(sum(bottles))
```

It prints 23 when it should be 25. What can I add to the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `divmod()` to get the quotient and remainder and fix `sample` such that it should be `quotient + remainder`:

```
x = 13
y = 2
bottles = [x]
sample = x
while sample // y != 0:
    quotient, remainder = divmod(sample, y) # divmod(a, b) returns a tuple (a // b, a % b)
    bottles.append(quotient)
    sample = remainder + quotient

print(bottles)
print(sum(bottles))
```

Output:

```
[13, 6, 3, 2, 1]
25
```

Comment: It doesn't work correctly if `x=12` and `y=5` :< the variables in the question are just samples, sorry for the confusion

Comment: please check now, there were some errors I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This might work using the mod sign as it gives you the remainder of a quotient.

```
x = 13
y = 2
bottles = [x]
mods = []
sample = x
while sample // y != 0:
    sample = sample // y
    mods.append(sample % y)
    bottles.append(sample)
bSum = sum(bottles)
mSum = sum(mods)
print(bSum + mSum)
```

Comment: It doesn't work correctly if `x=10` and `y=2` :< I think this only works on specific cases

Answer (score 0):

This does the Job

```
x = 13
xy = x
y = 2
bottles = [x]
sample = x
sums=0
while sample! =1:
    x = sample//y
    xy = x
    sample-=x
        if sample==1 or sample==0:
             if sample==1:
               bottles.append(xy) 
        break
    bottles.append(xy) 

for i in bottles:
    sums+=i
print(sums)
```

Comment: end is not defined tho

Comment: Sorry forgot to change end to xy it works now